# dynamically generate query based on current date

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have an external table `mytable`. We have a job scheduled in Airflow that picks up an SQL file and executes it once a day.

On a daily basis, I need to add a partition to the table corresponding to that day.
So for 2019-09-27, I would need to execute

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE ADD PARTITION(year=2018,month=9,day=27,ts=1538006400) location '/path/to/data/20180927/'
```

I can get the year/month/day using `SELECT year/month/day(current_date)` and the timestamp using `select unix_timestamp(CURRENT_DATE, 'yyyy-MM-dd')`, but how would I write an SQL query that would generate the entire `ALTER TABLE... ADD PARTITION` query as above?

Scripting it is an easy way but I need this done in SQL alone.

Answer (score 0):

Hive conf has a variable for current date  `current_date` you can used it as

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE ADD PARTITION (ts= '${hiveconf:current_date}')
```

functions `current_date` is now available in Hive 1.2.0 and higher.

Comment: Thanks - but how would I add the location clause? This is an external partitioned table.